# Public Extensions in Swift : Float vs Float.type

Tags: swift, swift2, swift-extensions

I'm trying to build an extension for floats in Swift that returns an enum (case .Positive for positive, .Negative for negative). I built an enum first.

```
public enum Sign 
{
    case Positive,Negative
}
```

Now, for the extension,

```
public extension Float
{
    public static func sign()-> Sign
    {
        if self < Float(0)
        {
            return Sign.Negative
        }
        else
        {
            return Sign.Positive
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting

> Cannot convert value of type 'Float.Type' to expected argument type

For the line

```
 if self < Float(0)
```

But that shouldn't be happening, considering that 'self' inside an extension for Float, should remain a float.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are using `static`:

```
public static func sign()-> Sign { ... }
```

`self` in this function refers to the type (the `Float` struct) rather than the instance (a floating point number). Remove the `static` and you'll be fine.

Comment: Oh. God. I'm an idiot sometimes.  I totally missed that. Thanks!

Comment: Don't worry. Everyone has moments they are not so proud of.

Comment: @RobinThuranMalhotra If this answers your question, please accept it

Answer (score 1):

First thing you are using it with static as @codedifferent already explained and second if there is already a property `isMinus` then why are using your own logic?

Simply use this to reduce number of lines of code:

```
public extension Float  {
 public  func sign()-> Sign {
  return  self.isSignMinus ? Sign.Negative : Sign.Positive

 }
}
```

Comment: Maybe include a description of why using `static` its breaking it? Great answer though, I like that you pointed out `isSignMinus`.

Comment: That's a super simple solution. Thanks!